# NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Tags: python, driver

Well, I'm studying Python for the first time. I need help with this code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
class CursoAutomacao:
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--lang-pt-BR')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Daniel pc\Desktop\Tutorial chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

    def Iniciar(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.mercadolivre.com.br')

curso = CursoAutomacao()
curso.Iniciar()
```

When I run this code this error appears: `NameError: **name 'driver' is not defined**.`
What could be happening? My window of Chrome opens but close very quick.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self.driver = ...` in your `init` method.

In totality:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class CursoAutomacao:
    def init(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--lang-pt-BR')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Daniel\pc\Desktop\Tutorial\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

    def Iniciar(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.mercadolivre.com.br')

curso = CursoAutomacao()
curso.Iniciar()
```

Comment: Thanks M Z.
Na verdade errei aqui:
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang-pt-BR')
o certo é : chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=pt-BR')
122/5000
In fact I went wrong here:
chrome_options.add_argument ('- lang-pt-BR')
the right thing is: chrome_options.add_argument ('- lang = en-BR')